# Match only first and last 4 numbers using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

So i want to match the first number and the last four numbers using regex.

I am able to get the last 4 numbers using `\d(?=\d{4})` but unable to get the first and last four numbers together. Tried multiple combinations.

Comment: Can you provide some test cases?

Comment: Try [`\b\d(?=\d*(?:\D*\d+){0,3}\D*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/rDMYmt/2). BTW, by "numbers", do you mean *integer* numbers?

Answer (score 0):

**String with Numbers and other characters**

```
^.*?(\d).*(\d).*?(\d).*?(\d).*?(\d).*?$
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OWSL5F/1/)

Captures the first number in the string, and then captures the last 4 numbers (all individually, allowing any characters in between).

Breakdown:

- `^.*?` - Lazily match everything
- `(\d)` - until it encounters and captures the first number
- `.*` - Greedily match everything
- `(\d).*?(\d).*?(\d).*?(\d).*?$` - until it encounters the last 4 numbers with anything in between them, capturing only the numbers. (`$` for the end of the string)

**Just Numbers**

If instead you want to capture these with numbers only:

```
^(\d)\d+(\d{4})$
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OWSL5F/2)